# Can the 3MB apex limit be increased?

Tags: apex, governorlimits

We have a salesforce org running a large customized crm application, integrations and a large customer portal force.com site. Everything is well managed and running fine, but based on a lot of Apex ... we've hit the 3MB  apex governor limit.

```
The maximum amount of code used by all Apex code in an organization is 3 MB.
```

The error message is actually phrased as:

```
Error: The total size of apex code in this application after removing comments exceeds the maxiumum character size of 3000000
```

(including the spelling error)

We know that there still are old testMethods not in `@isTest` annotated classes, but even after cleaning those up, how can we avoid running into this again in the future. Is this a limit that can be raised through SF support ?

Comment: I think yes and would better ask SF support directly.

Comment: Community can be much faster than Sf support, and this gets the information out there, available to all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. I have worked with Orgs where this limit has been increased. Raise a case with SF support.
A few have had it increased to 6MB
I am sure if you explain the steps that you have taken (cleaning up the code and checking for test methods) then this will aid your case.

Answer (score 6):

As per Salesforce Summer ’18 Release Note (preview),  Apex Code Size Limit has been increased.

> The maximum amount of Apex code that you can use in an org has been
>   doubled, from 3 MB to 6 MB. If your org was previously approved for an
>   increase above 6 MB, it remains unchanged.

**Where**: This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_code_size_limit.htm